# Sloping Binary Numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, base-conversion, binary

Given an integer `n`, output the first `n` sloping binary numbers, either 0- or 1-indexed. They are called this because of how they are generated:

Write numbers in binary under each other (right-justified):

```
........0
........1
.......10
.......11
......100
......101
......110
......111
.....1000
.........
```

Then, you need to take each diagonal from bottom-left to top-right, such that each final digit is the final digit of a diagonal. Here's the fourth diagonal (zero-indexed) marked with `x`'s, which is `100`:

```
........0
........1
.......10
.......11
......10x
......1x1
......x10
......111
.....1000
.........
```

The upward-sloping diagonals in order are:

```
0
11
110
101
100
1111
1010
.......
```

Then, convert to decimal, giving `0, 3, 6, 5, 4, 15, 10, ...`

[**OEIS A102370**](http://oeis.org/A102370)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **the shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: I don't think this specification is very clear.   I had to do a good deal of external reading before I could understand what was being asked here.

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/a/6Ht4q)'s a visualization, if it helps. Read the "ovals" top to bottom, and within the oval from bottom left to top right. Those give you the binary numbers you need to convert to decimal.

Comment: What do you mean, "*either 0- or 1-indexed*"? Do you mean that one may output either the first `n` or the first `n+1` numbers?

Comment: @Flp.Tkc yes, thanks for pointing that out. I edited the question and tagged it as such. (not OP)

Comment: Hopefully I made it clearer.

Comment: I think this might have allowed more interesting answers if you just had to return the n'th value.

Comment: @xnor I thought people might just use the formula on OEIS either way. I didn't know which would be better.

Comment: The specification makes sense to me, but if you're going to output the first N numbers sloped up like this, shouldn't you be generating the first N + binlen(N) or so numbers?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I never put a limit on how many to generate. I simply said "write numbers in binary...". You generate as many as you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Jelly, 11 bytes

```
ḤḶBUz0ŒDUḄḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ARoA5f//4bik4bi2QlV6MMWSRFXhuIThuKP///82OA)

#### Explanation

```
ḤḶBUz0ŒDUḄḣ    Main link. Argument: n
Ḥ              Double the argument. This ensures there are enough
               rows, since n + log2(n) <= 2n.
 Ḷ             Get range [0 .. 2n-1].
  B            Convert each number to binary.
   U           Reverse each list of digits. 
    z0         Transpose, padding with zeroes to a rectangle.
      ŒD       Get the diagonals of the rectangle, starting from the
               main diagonal. This gets the desired numbers, reversed,
               in binary, with some extras that'll get dropped.
        U      Reverse each diagonal.
         Ḅ     Convert each diagonal from binary to a number.
          ḣ    Take the first n numbers.
```

The transpose is the simplest way to pad the array for the diagonals builtin to work. Then the reverses are added to get everything in the correct order.

Comment: The implementation of the OEIS formula might also be really short in Jelly.

Comment: @TuukkaX Might be. I'm tired enough to find picking an upper limit for the sum hard.

Comment: @TuukkaX I tried it, but I don't see it happening. I'm sure Dennis & co will implement it in 5 bytes or so.

Comment: Currently [you are lucky](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104275/61532) ;)

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), 53 bytes

```
n=>[...Array(n)].map(g=(j=1,i)=>j>i?0:j&i|g(j+j,i+1))
```

0-indexed. It's not often I get to use a recursive function as a parameter to `map`.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 46 bytes

```
Plus@@@Table[BitAnd[n+k,2^k],{n,0,#},{k,0,n}]&
```

Unnamed function taking a nonnegative integer `#` as input and returning the 0-index sequence up to the `#`th term. Constructs the sloping binary numbers using `BitAnd` (bitwise "and") with appropriate powers of 2.

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, <s>63</s> 61 bytes

```
lambda i:[sum(n+k&2**k for k in range(n+1))for n in range(i)]
```

Uses the formula from OEIS.

-2 bytes thanks to [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)! `i+1` --> `i`

Comment: Can you explain how you went from `Sum_{ k >= 1 such that n + k == 0 mod 2^k } 2^k` to that simpler bitwise formula?

Comment: @smls It just calculates the upward diagonals directly. I actually thought it was more obvious than the other form.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
:q"@tt:+5MW\~fWs+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29VqORQUmKlbeobHlOXFl6s/f@/kQEA)

This uses the formula from OEIS:

```
a(n) = n + Sum_{ k in [1 2... n] such that n + k == 0 mod 2^k } 2^k
```

Code:

```
:q"     % For k in [0 1 2 ...n-1], where n is implicit input
  @     %   Push k
  tt    %   Push two copies
  :     %   Range [1 2 ... k]
  +     %   Add. Gives [n+1 n+2 ... n+k]
  5M    %   Push [1 2... k] again
  W     %   2 raised to that
  \     %   Modulo
  ~f    %   Indices of zero entries
  W     %   2 raised to that
  s     %   Sum of array
  +     %   Add
        % End implicitly. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 68 bytes

```php
for(;$n++<$argv[1];print$s._)for($s=$i=0;$i<$n;)$s|=$n+$i-1&1<<$i++;
```

takes input from command line argument, prints numbers separated by underscores. Run with `-r`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>59</s> 43 bytes

```
{map ->\n{n+sum map {2**$_ if 0==(n+$_)%(2**$_)},1..n},^$_}
```

```
{map {sum map {($_+$^k)+&2**$k},0..$_},^$_}
```

Uses the formula from the OESIS page.
Update: Switched to the bitwise-and based formula from [TuukkaX's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104260/14880).

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 67 bytes

```
{map {:2(flip [~] map {.base(2).flip.comb[$++]//""},$_..2*$_)},^$_}
```

Naive solution.
Converts the numbers that are part of the diagonal to base 2, takes the correct digit of each, and converts the result back to base 10.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
2*ḍ+
ḶçÐ€ḶUḄ+Ḷ’
```

This would be shorter than the other Jelly answer if we had to print only the **n**<sup>th</sup> term.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2@k9XBHrzbXwx3bDi8/POFR0xogK/ThjhZtIP2oYeb////NAQ)

Answer (score 0):

### R, 66 bytes

```
function(n,k=0:length(miscFuncs::bin(n-1)))sum(bitwAnd(k+n-1,2^k))
```

Unnamed function which uses the `bin` function from the `miscFuncs` package to calculate the length of `n` represented in binary and then using one of the OEIS formulas.